# Apache Prepending Header Information to ALL FILES

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, http-headers

We're in the middle of setting up new servers, and have been having some odd problems with Apache.

Apache is prepending text that looks like this:

```
$15plðI‚‚�E�ðA™@�@��yeÔ|~Ÿ²�PÎ³Z" zS€�8i³��
,ÀŠ{ÿBHTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 02 Feb 2009 22:28:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Feb 2009 22:28:05 GMT
ETag: W/"1238007d-2224e-fe617f40"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 139854
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
```

To all files. The file I copied the above text from is the prototype library js file. As loaded from our server.

I've searched, but couldn't find much about this problem Maybe I don't know what I'm searching for...

Anyway, if anyone has seen this behaviour before, could they please let me know either 1) how to fix it so that this content is not prepended to all files, or 2) where to look for further help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this happen once, due to a mismatch between shared libraries on my NetBSD machine and what Apache was linked with.  Bad Things were happening, and I never did fully trace it down.  A full recompile of the OS (I'm a NetBSD developer) and the pkgsrc (all the stuff like apache) "fixed" it.

Comment: I think this is the approach we will take, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable unneeded modules